# Audit Report With User IDs as Numbers

Tags: sharepoint-server, active-directory, reports, auditing

I recently turned on auditing for a specific list.  After producing a custom report to check usage data, we noticed the report contains several 3 and four digit numbers in the user ID column instead of user names.

We have no AD users who have or ever had these numbers as IDs.  What could be the source of these numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely their ID that points to the User Information List where all site users are stored. Each user has an underlying numerical ID per site collection as each site collection stores its own copy of user data in the User Information List.

It can be found at `http://yoursp/managedpath/sitecollection/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx`

Comment: That definitely looks like the number.  Any idea why it might reference the ID in some cases rather than the user name?

Comment: Possibly if the users were disabled in Active directory, I'm not quite certain.